# How to retrieve a session scoped object list using JSTL?

Tags: java, session, jstl, el

Say I have a static class A which has several public final static fields.

```
public class Foo{
    public static final String A_STRING = "a_string";
}
```

And I have also some class which will set a list in session, like this:

`List<Bar>barList = getBarList();
 session.setAttribute(Foo.A_STRING, barList);`

I want to access this list from jsp and iterate through each Bar object and output each Bar objects fields.

What I have come up with this:

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope[Foo.A_STRING]}" var="element">
<tr>
<td>${element.id}</td>
td>${element.name}</td>
...
</tr></c:forEach>
```

which is not working, any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `Foo.A_STRING` will not get resolved, instead try this `${sessionScope[a_string]}`

Comment: does not work. However, ${sessionScope.a_string} does work but I do not want that. I do not want to hard code the string literal.

Answer (score 0):

First, change `${sessionScope[Foo.A_STRING]}` to `${sessionScope.a_string}`.

Second, you have inconsistent variable name (`elements` and `element`), change either one of them to make it consistent.

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.a_string}" var="element">
    <tr>
        <td>${element.id}</td>
        <td>${element.name}</td>
    ...
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does work but I do not want to hard code "a_string". Is there a way around ? The second issue is fixed. It was a typo. Thanks for noticing.